# Volume creation MAPR

Tags: linux, mapr

I am pretty new to MapR and I have a task about creating a MapR volume. I used this command

```
maprcli volume create -name test-volume -path /MyCluster/apps/application_logs/node1
```

to create the volume but I get this error:

```
ERROR (2) -  Failed to mount test-volume, parent of mount dir /MyCluster/apps/application_logs/node1 does not exist, No such file or directory
```

Before running the command I created this path '/MyCluster/apps/application_logs/node1' using **mkdir** :

Does anyone know why I get this error and if someone can help me with fixing it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say;

> I created this path '/MyCluster/apps/application_logs/node1' using mkdir

I assume that you have created it in local file system. The `path` parameter needs to be created in `MapR` file system.

To do that, you can either create the dir by interacting with `MapR` file system directly as follows;

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p <path>
```

or you can mount `MapR` fs to local file system so that you can interact with it from mount point; `/mapr/<cluster-name>/`

From the [doc](https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/61/ReferenceGuide/volume-create.html?hl=maprcli%2Cvolume%2Ccreated);

```
Parameter: path
     Default Value: No default value 
     Possible Values: Any valid path. 
     Description: The path at which to mount the volume. The path must be relative to / and cannot be in the form of a global namespace path (for example, /mapr/<cluster-name>/).
```